# Keeping same font size while rescaling scientific figures and graphs

Tags: ms-word, scaling, inkscape

I am currently preparing different graphs and figures for a scientific publication. However, I am facing the challenge of keeping the same font size (12) while re-scaling both in my Word document.

An example would be: I prepare three graphs in Excel using font size 12. Then, I merge them to a large figure using InkScape. Finally, I import the figure in my Word document and scale it, so it fits into one column. However, as soon as I do this, the font size becomes gradually smaller, which is not accepted by the journal. It must remain constant.

Unfortunately, I am not able to pin down a solution. Similar happens for instance when I prepare my graphs with OriginLab. After importing and scaling them in Word, the font size changes.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use CTRL+A to select everything and set a standard font size, it will affect the entire document.

Comment: Unfortunately, the figures and tables are all .jpeg's so I cant change their font size in Word anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're scaling the size of a raster image, which means that inevitably all the text in the image will scale accordingly.

I suggest you increase the font size in Inkscape before you export it or copy it into Word.